# How can I inject a properties file with JDK only?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, java-7

Here is my class:

```
public class Foo {
   private static Properties conf;
}
```

If I manually load `conf`, I could do it this way (error handling code ommitted for the sake of clarity):

```
public class Foo {
   private static Properties conf;

   static {
      InputStream is =... // Get the properties file as Stream from classpath

      conf = new Properties();
      conf.load(is);

      // ...
   }
}
```

Now, I want to remove all this garbage for something like this:

```
public class Foo {
   @javax.annotation.Resource(name="my-file-on-classpath.properties")
   private static Properties conf;
}
```

I know I could do it with *Spring* or anything similar.

However, is it possible to accomplish this by using the JDK **only** ?

Comment: For the curious, Spring provides a resource loader usable as is : `DefaultResourceLoader`. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of CDI requires a CDI container. This is not included in JavaSE. You have to use an additional one like Spring for example. It's defined in JavaEE 6.